# Remove all global variables at once in Postman

Tags: postman

I am wondering if there is a way to remove all the global variables clicking somewhere in Postman. I know how to use environment variables and how to switch among them but I want to get rid of all the global variables at once.

Comment: There isn't a 'clear all' type setting or button in the app, only the `pm.globals.clear()` command from the sandbox.

Comment: That's huge. I didn't know that option is available. After calling it, do they all global variables disappear from the UI as well?

Comment: Yes, it clears all global variables for the current Workspace, and yes, can't get access to them from the UI.

Comment: If this is added into a single request, a Folder or a Collection Pre-request Script or Tests sandbox, it will clear all the global variables. The same `.clear()` function can also be used on the environment and collectionVariables too. To clear an individual variable, use the `.unset('var_name')` function.